# iPad randomly restarts every few minutes

Tags: ipad, jailbreak, ios, restart, springboard

Starting from a few days ago, my iPad mini(1st gen) was restarting every 3-5 minutes. I tried to normally restore, then recovery mode restore, and today DFU restore mode. None of these methods worked. My warranty is already expired, so I cannot bring it into an Apple store. How do I fix this problem?

EDIT: I jailbroke my iPad today, hoping to find a solution to the problem in Cydia. When I was downloading a tweak, the "restart springboard" after downloading would restart my device. Could there be a problem with springboard?

EDIT 2: I realized that it would have a period of time that it wouldn't autorestart(usually 2-3 hours), then restart approx every 30secs-2mins.

Comment: First guess would be the battery is fried. Apple store would be your best bet.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'd rather not go into an Apple store to get it fixed, because my warranty is already expired and I would rather spend it on a new iPad.

Comment: Wherever you go to get it fixed, they'll charge you for it. I'd rather an Apple store than try save 10 bucks in some back street guesswork emporium.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm trying DIY fixes, and if those don't work, just planning to abandon it.

Comment: Then it's time to abandon it.

Comment: You can get an OEM battery for $20 online. If you're abandoning it, mail it to me at. . . For $20 COD. Just kidding. Partly.

Comment: Did you receive any strange iMessages (or WhatsApp messages)? [If yes, you should read this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204897)

Comment: @idmean I did not.

Comment: When you restored, did you also restore your backup? If so, try restoring the iPad to factory defaults without restoring your backup. It could be related to some corrupt files (plist?)

Comment: @Brethil I restored from my backup from restore, which didn't work, so I tried to restore it to factory defaults from DFU mode. None worked. (In fact, the time I restored from DFU mode, it restarted before I even set up/had an option to choose a backup.)